# Render html from PHP step-by-step

Tags: php, html

One of the most commonly cited arguments against using tables for layout is that it slows down the rendering of a page. The conventional wisdom appears to be that if a page loads slowly, it's better to load the page step-by-step so the user can see what's happening, than it is to wait for everything to be loaded and then render it all at once. Fair enough.

So, how would you achieve this with a slow/cumbersome PHP script? If you have a page that needs to do an insane number of calculations/mysql queries or something, but you want it to show the progress as it works through them? For example..

```
<?
echo "<p>counting to a million (repeatedly)...</p>";

$foo = 0;
for ($c=1; $c<=10; $c+=1) {
  for ($b=1; $b<=10; $b+=1) {
    for ($a=1; $a<=1000000; $a+=1) {
      $foo+=1;
    }
  }
  echo "<p>still counting... ($c of 10)</p>";
}

echo "<p>all done!</p>";
?>
```

This code would leave you waiting a while (e.g. 10s), then load all the paragraphs in one go. Is it possible to make it render "still counting..." one by one (e.g. one per second) as the PHP was still executing the rest of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your question doesn't make much sense. The *browser* is slow at rendering a page once it has fetched all HTML source. The slow rendering isn't due to PHP. PHP just outputs HTML source code. It can do that with tables as fast as with any other HTML of the same size.

However, when outputting the HTML is slow (regardless of tables or not), you may use the [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) command to "flush" the content PHP has rendered so far.

Note though, that there may be buffering in the server software, in the browser, and maybe in other steps inbetween, so it's not guaranteed that every outputted table row will appear right away in the browser.

A different approach would be to use JavaScript to show a 'splash' screen. The disadvantage is that that you cannot tell using JavaScript how far the loading is. Anyway, an example, using a slow loading image.

Right at the start of the body is a script that adds a class to the body. That class makes sure a 'splash screen' (body::before) is shown. When the whole page is loaded, an event fires which removes the splash screen. I used a slow loading image from Deelay.me, but a similar feature could work for you. However, take into account what I said about buffering. It's not guaranteed that the first part of the document is already going to be processed by the browser, even when you use `flush()`.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.body.className = "";
});
```

```css
body.js.loading::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 500%;
  vertical-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(50,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  content: "Loading...";
}
```

```html
<body>
<script>document.body.className="js loading";</script>
<p>Chunk of text content before a very slow image.
<p><img src="http://deelay.me/1000/http://deelay.me/img/1000ms.gif">
<p>Chunk of text after very slow image.
</body>
```

A completely different approach might be to load parts of your page using JavaScript and Ajax. You can load a simple, light page and load the heavier part in a separate request. You could load these in iframes, but that can be a bit icky. Loading them through JavaScript is cleaner, but take into account that you *may* exclude a small part of your target audience if they don't have JavaScript enabled for whatever reason.